# Fb Like button + Permission denied for <http://www.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger

Tags: javascript, facebook, exception, facebook-like

At this point I'm nearly to take my hair off, actually I'm working with an rudimentary way to "vote" content in a website with the fb-like button and a copy into the website database, so, I suscribed an ajax call into the **edge.create** and **edge.remove** events of the like button...

The problem is at the moment of make a "like", the facebook part works fine, the user updates its facebook status as is supposed to be, but, in the meantime an Exception is throwed "***uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for http://www.facebook.com to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger***" so it DOESN'T end the work (do the ajax call), and also the next time that the fb like button is render it DOESN'T take a fresh status, it remains as if no one has "liked" it before.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="post-vote" >
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="the_link" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count"  data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
<div id="fb-root" class="clearfix"></div>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId: 'the_app_id',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      channelURL : '[site]/channel.php'
   });

   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
      console.log("Catch like event");
      window.doAjaxVoteUp();
   });

   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
      console.log("Catch UNlike event");
      window.doAjaxVoteDown();
    });
};

(function() {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); 
   e.type = 'text/javascript';
   e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js';
   e.async = true;
   document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Actually exist a question and it seems to be resolve with the same issues [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8105778/uncaught-exception-error-permission-denied-for-https-www-facebook-com-to-g) but I'm just working with facebook JAVASCRIPT sdk.

So... I'll be glad with any help. Thanks

Comment: Added "channelURL" into the FB.init now I have an unexpected behavior... Sometimes do the ajax call (15% of times). Also catch an exception from Webkit inspector concerning about the access to a frame without the same protocol http / https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer *(BTW thanks fb for the so HELPLESS error reporting)* the problem was that i haven't set correctly the Open Graph meta data, to be specific was the **og:url** and the **fb:app_id**.

The problem with the protocols, i think was fault of the og:url. The [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) was a great help.

Comment: You cannot use localhost in the og:url since Facebook cannot surf that page to get the data. So when developing, enter the live site URL in og:url, og:image, the like/share button url etc.